# Is there a "correct" folder where to place test resources in dart?

Tags: dart, directory

I have a simple dart class I am trying to test.
To test it I need to open a txt file, feed the content to an instance of the class and check that the output is correct.

Where do I place this txt file? The txt file is useless outside of testing.

Also, related, how do I acess its directory consistently? I tried placing it in the test folder, but the problem is that:

```
System.currentDirectory
```

Returns a different directory if I am running the test on its own or the script calling all the other test dart files on at a time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I check if System.currentDirectory is the directory containing the `pubspec.yaml` file, if not I move the current directory upwards until I found the directory containing the `pubpsec.yaml` file and then continue with the test code.

Comment: Unfortunately I can't do this. System.currentDirectory is inconsistent. When running the tests in dart editor it is the pubspec.yaml directory, but in intellij it is the directory containing the .dart file. I really need something a more consistent call

Comment: But that is what my answer is about. Check if the directory contains the `pubspec.yaml` file, if not move the current directory one level up until the directory contains the `pubspec.yaml` file. From there always use a relative path to the text file starting from the directory containing `pubspec.yaml'.

Comment: ohhhh, thanks. I see, now. It was a bit of a pain, to be honest, but it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like package https://pub.dev/packages/resource is also suitable for this now.

Comment: The `resource` package has been discontinued as of `2.1.7`. Converting a `package:` URI to a platform specific URI "no longer makes sense when a large number of Dart programs are ahead-of-time compiled"

Answer (score 1):

I have still not found a definitive answer to this question. I've been looking for something similar to the `testdata` directory in Go and the `src/test/resources` directory in Java.

I'm using Android studio and have settled on using a `test_data.dart` file at the top of my `test` directory.  In there I define my test data (mostly JSON) and then import it into my individual tests.  This doesn't help if you need to deal with binary files but it has been useful for my JSON data. I'll also inject the JSON language with `//language=json` so I can open the fragment in a separate window to format.

```dart
//language=json
const consolidatedWeatherJson = '''{
  "consolidated_weather": [
    {
      "id": 4907479830888448,
      "weather_state_name": "Showers",
      "weather_state_abbr": "s",
      "wind_direction_compass": "SW",
      "created": "2020-10-26T00:20:01.840132Z",
      "applicable_date": "2020-10-26",
      "min_temp": 7.9399999999999995,
      "max_temp": 13.239999999999998,
      "the_temp": 12.825,
      "wind_speed": 7.876886316914553,
      "wind_direction": 246.17046093256732,
      "air_pressure": 997.0,
      "humidity": 73,
      "visibility": 11.037727173307882,
      "predictability": 73
    }
  ]
}
''';
```

Using the `Alt` + `Enter` key combination will bring up the **Edit JSON Fragment** option.  Selecting that open the fragment in a new editor and any changes made there (formatting for example) will be updated in the fragment.

Not perfect but it solves my issues.